# Kibana service running, but no response from browser

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have my kibana running normal but I can't open the link from browser.

Please find the Kibana logs below,

```
  log   [14:09:05.036] [info][status][plugin:kibana] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [14:09:05.065] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [14:09:05.100] [info][status][plugin:shield] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [14:09:05.103] [info][status][plugin:kbn_vislib_vis_types] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [14:09:05.111] [info][status][plugin:markdown_vis] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [14:09:05.116] [info][status][plugin:metric_vis] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [14:09:05.118] [info][status][plugin:spyModes] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [14:09:05.128] [info][status][plugin:statusPage] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [14:09:05.132] [info][status][plugin:table_vis] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [14:09:05.136] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch] Status changed from yellow to green - Kibana index ready
  log   [14:09:05.140] [info][listening] Server running at https://0.0.0.0:5600
```

I tried the elasticsearch by

```
curl localhost:9200
```

It shows,

```
{
  "name" : "Scream",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.3",
    "build_hash" : "218bdf10790eef486ff2c41a3df5cfa32dadcfde",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-05-17T15:40:04Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

but for kibana:

```
curl localhost:5600

curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Please find my kibana config,

```
port: 5600
# The host to bind the server to.
host: "0.0.0.0"
# The Elasticsearch instance to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch_url: "http://localhost:9200"
```

Comment: do u see any node.js process running?

Comment: Hi @MrunalGosar, I `ps -ef|grep node.js` but doesn't see anything.

Comment: Just try `ps -ef | grep node` (without `.js`) you should see a process running `bin/../node/bin/node bin/../src/cli`

Comment: @Val I can found the process now. `./bin/../node/bin/node ./bin/../src/cli` What should I do for this process? I think it means Kibana process is running

Comment: Just making sure it's running... Not sure though why you get an empty reply. Have you tried in your browser?

Comment: @Val Yes, I also tried from the browser. I am trying to install the `shiled` into Kibana plugin then the browser doesn't work now

Comment: Have you installed the license plugin?

Comment: @Val No, should I?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/2.3/installing-shield.html

Comment: @Val I think it may cause the problem. should I install the `shiled` both in elasticsearch and kibana? Currently, only kibana have `shiled` plugin

Comment: Both. If you follow this [official tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/2.3/kibana.html), it should work

Comment: Have you tried port 5601 or did you change it on purpose?

Answer (score 4):

Problem is quite old but in case someone ends up here - make sure to use "https".
The fineprint does say that "ignore the self-signed certificate error" :)

Comment: Yes, this is not intuitive because even on localhost, you must specify https, and proceed through the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was stack in same issue.
I think the problem is occurred when you do port forwarding.

You have to set 0.0.0.0:5601 as a source port.

Comment: Hey @kusa, I tried your solution `kubectl port-forward svc/kibana-http  5601 --address='0.0.0.0'`, but still not working, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the latest GitHub 5.5.0 install and when I tried to bring up the localhost, IE just said Kibana LOADING...

However, I installed Chrome and Kibana popped right up. So the solution is to use a different browser.